# Setup role so that role is owner of sequence or table role made

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

I want to allow a users assigned to a role to delete their own content in postgres but not content made by admins. I am new to database management and thought that the below would work but doesn't.

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO analyst;

GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO analyst;
```

Comment: Please define how "their own content" can be recognized. If it is by some column values, row level security may be the answer.

Comment: Thanks, if users creates table user can delete table otherwise they may not.

Comment: If I understand you right, that's how it works by default. Only a superuser and the table owner can run `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks, that how I thought it should work. But it isn't, I was testing as a role with login rather than a user assigned to role

Comment: I don't understand your latest comment. Maybe you should add some SQL code to your question that demonstrates the problem. As it is, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use row level security. Docs : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Ex :

```
CREATE POLICY analyst_policy
ON public.mytable
USING (user = CURRENT_USER);
```